# Eway Payment gateway Iframe

Tags: payment-gateway

I had implemented Eway payment gateway using the Iframe. When user is registering for the first time credit card registration form is shown.So can we hide any elements in it like amount and login button.As I am using this is to just for registration to eway for future payments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the eWAY IFrame, the login buttons and some other features can be disabled in the "Shared Page" settings of MYeWAY (see [this article for more info](https://go.eway.io/s/article/Can-I-customize-the-eWAY-hosted-Payment-page)). The amount can't be changed at this time.

Comment: Thanks for answer and link.I am able to customize the shared page but not able to change the text of Pay Now button.Do you have any idea how can we change the text of Pay Now button in shared Payment Page?

Comment: On the shared payment page? That can't be changed unfortunately.